# Adding a Partition FOR 30 DAYS

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning, partition, database-partitioning

I have the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE "ICTPART_DAILY_SUMMARY"
   (    
   
   "EVENT_START_DATE" DATE
   "ACCOUNTING_METHOD" CHAR(1), 
    ......etc 
    )
PARTITION BY RANGE ("EVENT_START_DATE") 
 (PARTITION "ICTPART_DAY_SUM_P20220218"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2022-02-19 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 
  TABLESPACE "TBS_ICTQUO_D" , 
PARTITION "ICTPART_DAY_SUM_P20220219"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2022-02-20 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "TBS_ICTQUO_D" , 
PARTITION "ICTPART_DAY_SUM_PMAX"  VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 
  TABLESPACE "TBS_ICTQUO_D" ) ;
```

This table is being partitioned everyday as you can see by an old ksh script.

i want to continue the same work with an sql script who run every first of the month and alter that table and do the same daily partition for 30 days.

for exemple : we are in 01/03/2022, i want to added partition for 01/03/2022 , 02/03/2022, 03/03/2022 ..... etc  until 31/03/2022

that sql script will be putted in a ETL who run every first of the month and do that partition

Answer (score 0):

Why not get rid of the ksh script and use INTERVAL PARTITIONs. This way a new PARTITION will be automatically created when a new day is inserted in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (     
 seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
   dt   DATE
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (dt)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
(
   PARTITION OLD_DATA values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2022-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
);
/

INSERT into t1 (dt)
with dt (dt, interv) as (
select date '2022-01-01', numtodsinterval(1,'DAY') from dual
union all
select dt.dt + interv, interv from dt
where dt.dt + interv < date '2022-02-01')
select dt from dt;
/
```

Comment: I talked to my client about this , 

He  want to add the partition before the insert ..

That means we add the partition of the same day ( forget about 30 days we will run it every day so one day partition will be enough ) before the insert .. 

any ideas about this please 

and i need to keep the name of the partition like this "ICTPART_DAY_SUM_P20220219" with changes of the day of course P20220219 ...

Comment: If you were setup with a MAXVALUE you could create a process to split the PARTITION, which would create an empty partition. As for the name of the PARTITION that should be an innocuous to the user as they should be querying by value not PARTITION name. What problem is your client trying to solve with the pre-creation of empty partitions? It doesn't seem to make sense

Comment: @mohka Use interval partitioning and then [rename partitions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877) by daily scheduled job (if you wish). Oracle provides enough tools to work with partitions without knowing its name by using `partition for (value)`, which is more verbose than `someabbreviation_somedate`. Restriction by name should have a reason